# Order by SKU problem

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, product-sorting

I am trying to order products by SKU but I got it wrong 
The order is on the Order page (Checkout)
This is a snippet of my code

```
$this->_items->getSelect()->order('main_table.sku ASC');
$this->_items->getSelect()->group('main_table.item_id');
```

I am trying to order products having SKU :
4422; 00003001 and 00004335 
but I am gotten them in this order :

4422

00003001

00004335

How can I solve this problem, don't hesitate if you need more details?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that's the only order criteria in your select?

Comment: The other criteria is correct , about the brand and name, As I have worked on Zend before I think there is still missing something in this line $this->_items->getSelect()->order('main_table.sku ASC');

Comment: Are you trying to dump the sql query, let we see the result  of this : $this->_items->getSelect()->__toString();    or log it in custom log file like this Mage::log($this->_items->getSelect()->__toString(),null,'logfile.log',true);

Comment: instead of that Line , I have written var_dump($this->_items->getSelect()->__toString());

Comment: This is the output 
string 'SELECT `main_table`.*, `catalog_product_index_eav`.`value`, `eav_attribute_option`.*, `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code`, `eav_attribute_option_value`.`value` FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` ON product_id=catalog_product_index_eav.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option` ON catalog_product_index_eav.value=eav_attribute_option.option_id
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute` ON eav_attribute.attribute_id=catalog_product_index_eav.attribute_id
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute'... (length=761)

Comment: This is the solution of the problem :

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to the problem :

```
$this->_items->getSelect()->order("LPAD(main_table.sku, 10, '0') ASC");
$this->_items->getSelect()->group('main_table.item_id');
```